# Mysql database table does not update

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to java, i want to update my database table columns. but when running this code I'm getting this error.

> execom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Mcgreth' at
>   line 1

I tried for 1 week. but I cant even think where's the wrong. plzz help me..
thanks a lot for help.this is my code.

```
public boolean update(File2nd dt) {

    try {            
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);//get the connection
        String query = "UPDATE file1  SET  name='" + dt.getName()+ "',age='" + dt.getAge()+ "',color="+dt.getColor()+ ""

                + " WHERE name=" + dt.getName();

        pst = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);            
        pst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Updated queries: ");
        return true;
       } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exe" + e);
        return false;
       } finally {
        try {
              if (pst != null) {
                pst.close();
              }
              if (con != null) {
                con.close();
              }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the single quotes for the color field, and in the where clause.

```
"UPDATE file1  SET  name='" + dt.getName()+ "',age='" + dt.getAge()+ "',color='"+dt.getColor()+ "'"
+ " WHERE name='" + dt.getName() + "'";
```

Also, you should use paramaterized statements, for a lot of reasons: protection against sql injection, improved readability and often more efficient query execution by your DBMS.

```
"UPDATE file1  SET  name=?,age=?,color=? WHERE NAME =?";

pst.setString(1, dt.getName());
pst.setInt(2, dt.getAge());
(etc...)
```

Comment: I was just about to add an answer involving PreparedStatement with `?` placeholders and you beat me to it! Reasons include ease of maintainability and protection from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thank u soo much NickJ... it worked.. And i would like to know how to keep a selected row in jtable colored. plz help me with this.